# PHP Can I commit my config file on google code

Tags: database, svn, zend-framework

Is there a problem with committing my zend framework code on googlecode (specifically my config file containing db parameters). I.E., can someone hack into my db if the config file has my db credentials? id have to have my db local to the server, instead of having a db host which somoene could potentially hack into.

Comment: well, putting credentials in a public place is never a good idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may or may not lead to problems ultimately, but it is certainly a bad idea.

Set your .gitignore to ignore your config file and you can commit away without having those credentials in a public place.  (Just make sure you have your config file backed up somewhere.)

Ultimately, you may want to consider making a build process that will create the appropriate config for the appropriate server.  It could read the credentials from a file on your server or a protected central entity or have the user enter them or whatever.  That may reduce the temptation to check in credentials without as much resultant deployment hassles.